# How to implement summation using parallel reduction in OpenCL?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, opencl

I'm trying to implement a kernel which does parallel reduction. The code below works on occasion, I have not been able to pin down why it goes wrong on the occasions it does.

```
__kernel void summation(__global float* input, __global float* partialSum, __local float *localSum){
int local_id = get_local_id(0);
int workgroup_size = get_local_size(0);
localSum[local_id] = input[get_global_id(0)];

for(int step = workgroup_size/2; step>0; step/=2){
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if(local_id < step){
    localSum[local_id] += localSum[local_id + step];
    }
}
if(local_id == 0){
    partialSum[get_group_id(0)] = localSum[0];
}}
```

Essentially I'm summing the values per work group and storing each work group's total into partialSum, the final summation is done on the host. Below is the code which sets up the values for the summation.

```
size_t global[1];
size_t local[1];

const int DATA_SIZE = 15000;
float *input = NULL;
float *partialSum = NULL;
int count = DATA_SIZE;

local[0] = 2;
global[0] = count;
input = (float *)malloc(count * sizeof(float));
partialSum = (float *)malloc(global[0]/local[0] * sizeof(float));

int i;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
    input[i] = (float)i+1;
}
```

I'm thinking it has something to do when the size of the input is not a power of two? I noticed it begins to go off for numbers around 8000 and beyond. Any assistance is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm thinking it has something to do when the size of the input is not a power of two?

Yes. Consider what happens when you try to reduce, say, 9 elements. Suppose you launch 1 work-group of 9 work-items:

```
for (int step = workgroup_size / 2; step > 0; step /= 2){
    // At iteration 0: step = 9 / 2 = 4
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if (local_id < step) {
        // Branch taken by threads 0 to 3
        // Only 8 numbers added up together! 
        localSum[local_id] += localSum[local_id + step];
    }
}
```

You're never summing the 9th element, hence the reduction is incorrect. An easy solution is to pad the input data with enough zeroes to make the work-group size the immediate next power-of-two.

Comment: Thanks for the response, as a test I tried calculating the sums from 1 to 16384, with a work group size of 2. The sum resulted in 134226416 which is close to the actual answer (134225920). Given that I used a power of 2 here I should have gotten the correct answer right?

Comment: The reason you are not getting the correct answer for 1..16384 is the result of rounding errors when using 32-bit floats. Your kernel code is not the problem in this case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782731/opencl-reduction-result-wrong-with-large-floats/27786262#27786262

Comment: Great, you were absolutely correct, I was using a regular float to hold the running sum of all the partial sums. This was on the host. Changed it to double and all went well.