# Inaccurate results with OpenCL Reduction example

Tags: opencl

I am working with the OpenCL reduction example provided by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/OpenCL_Parallel_Reduction_Example/Introduction/Intro.html)

After a few days of dissecting it, I understand the basics; I've converted it to a version that runs more or less reliably on c++ (Openframeworks) and finds the largest number in the input set.

However, in doing so, a few questions have arisen as follows:

- why are multiple passes used? the most I have been able to cause the reduction to require is two; the latter pass only taking a very low number of elements and so being very unsuitable for an openCL process (i.e. wouldn't it be better to stick to a single pass and then process the results of that on the cpu?)
- when I set the 'count' number of elements to a very high number (24M and up) and the type to a float4, I get inaccurate (or totally wrong) results. Why is this?
- in the openCL kernels, can anyone explain what is being done here:

```
while (i < n){
        int a = LOAD_GLOBAL_I1(input, i);
        int b = LOAD_GLOBAL_I1(input, i + group_size);
        int s = LOAD_LOCAL_I1(shared, local_id);
        STORE_LOCAL_I1(shared, local_id, (a + b + s));
        i += local_stride;
}
```

as opposed to what is being done here?

```
#define ACCUM_LOCAL_I1(s, i, j) \
 { \
    int x = ((__local int*)(s))[(size_t)(i)]; \
    int y = ((__local int*)(s))[(size_t)(j)]; \
    ((__local int*)(s))[(size_t)(i)] = (x + y); \
 }
```

Thanks!
S

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first 2 questions:

> ```
> why are multiple passes used?
> ```

Reducing millions of elements to a few thousands can be done in parallel with a device utilization of almost 100%. But the final step is quite tricky. So, instead of keeping everything in one shot and have multiple threads idle, Apple implementation decided to do a first pass reduction; then adapt the work items to the new reduction problem, and finally completing it.
Ii is a very specific optimization for OpenCL, but it may not be for C++.

> when I set the 'count' number of elements to a very high number (24M
>   and up) and the type to a float4, I get inaccurate (or totally wrong)
>   results. Why is this?

A float32 precision is 2^23 the remainder. Values higher than 24M = 1.43 x 2^24 (in float representation), have an error in the range +/-(2^24/2^23)/2 ~= 1.

That means, if you do:

```
 float A=24000000;
 float B= A + 1; //~1 error here
```

The operator error is in the range of the data, therefore... big errors if you repeat that in a loop!

This will not happen in 64bits CPUs, because the 32bits float math uses internally 48bits precision, therefore avoiding these errors. However if you get the float close to 2^48 they will happen as well. But that is not the typical case for normal "counting" integers.

Comment: hey, thanks for the response. I understand the first one; tho I still wonder why the latter (much smaller) reduction isn't just run on the cpu. With the inaccuracy issue - yes, I thought that too (found the link suggested by the answer below) but when I tested the reduction using int4 instead of float4 the inaccuracies still came in. Is there a similar error range for an int4?

Comment: There is no innacuracies with "ints", so check your code. integer operations are always exact.

Comment: That's what I thought, ints can't be inaccurate! Aaand, I haven't edited the code from the apple example linked to above, so I'd expected it to be fine.  Yet it stops working accurately when run with over 23(ish)m elements when those elements are int4 or float4. From testing further, the exact same thing happens with errors occurring for a number over circa 45m elements for an int2, and somewhere over 91m for a plain old int. I know these are very high numbers(!) and so maybe not so critical, but I'm intrigued as to what is causing this.

Comment: I'm guessing it must just be a memory issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the precision of 32 bit floats. You're not the first person to ask about this either.  [OpenCL reduction result wrong with large floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782731/opencl-reduction-result-wrong-with-large-floats/27786262#27786262)

Comment: yes, I found this (see above comment) but it still gives a error result with a large set of int4 results